# Promise.all returns [[PromiseValue]] but I need array of all returned values

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I am trying to return array of json objects, but below code returns [[PromiseValue]] and data surely is there.

"results from function"

[image]

### How can I get array of json objects and set it to state

NOTE: if I call `.then(data => console.log(data))` inside `getEndResults` function that works but then I can't setState in there as it throws an error

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

```js
getUserCredits = async (userId, creditId) => {
    return await fetch(
    `${someLink}/userId/${userId}/credit/${creditId}`,
        {
            method: "GET",
        }
    )
}

getEndResult = async () => {
    const userId = await this.getUserId(userId);
    const userData = await this.getUserData(userId);

    const checkData = await Promise.all(userData.checks.map(check => {
    return check.checkIds.map((checkIds) => {
        return this.getUserCredits(userId ,checkIds)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data))
            // Can't setState here
            // .then(data => this.setState({ results: data }))
        })
    }))

    console.log(checkData);
}
```

Comment: Remove `.then(data => console.log(data))`. That's causing your promise to resolve with `undefined`

Comment: Yes, @Phil is correct, there isn't a return value from `console.log`, so you need to also `return data;` in that block;

Comment: `getUserCredits` might as well not be _async_. For all it does, you might as well have `getUserCredits = (userId, creditId) => fetch(\`${someLink}/userId/${userId}/credit/${creditId}\`)`

Comment: I replaced `.then(data => console.log(data))` with `.then(data => {return data})` and that returns same as shown in picture above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a 2-dimensional array of promises, and then passing that into Promise.all. Promise.all only knows how to work with single-dimensional arrays, so what it sees is an array with things that aren't promises. For non-promises, promises.all just immediately resolves to the value it was given.

You will need to flatten out your 2-d array before sending it to Promise.all. If you have a polyfill for [array.prototype.flatmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) (which will soon be added to javascript, but isn't there yet), this can be done like:

```
const checkData = await Promise.all(userData.checks.flatMap(check => {
  return check.checkIds.map((checkIds) => {
    return this.getUserCredits(userId, checkIds)
      .then(res => res.json());
  });
```

If that function is not available to you, then you could write your own function for flattening a 2d array, something like this:

```
function flatten(arr) {
  const result = [];
  arr.forEach(val => {
    if (Array.isArray(val)) {
      result.push(...val);
    } else {
      result.push(val);
    }
  });
  return result;
}

// used like:

const promises = flatten(userData.checks.map(check => {
  // ... etc
}));
const checkData = await Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: `flatMap` worked, I get the results just how I need them. just one last thing, if I setState `this.setState({ results: checkData })` It keeps rendering the result and never stop. unless application crashes. TX

Comment: Where are you calling getEndResult from? Sounds like it might be being called from render, or a componentDidUpdate without a check to make sure things changed.

Comment: I am setting it in getEndResults passing it in some other file as prop. you are right I console logged inside render. Thanks for help, really appropriate it

Comment: so if I setState in getEndResults function like `if(checkData !== null){ this.setState({ results: checkData }) }`. I haven't called `results` anywhere else just yet, but it keeps returning the results. All I need is once data is returned set the state of results and be able to use in child components